# mysql Select Query based on same table

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table promotions main fields are 
PromotionMaintenanceID (Primary)
PID
PromotionID
PromotionName

I have a special case where the PromotionID of one record (This will be the main Record) become the PID of some of some other records. I need to create a MySql statement to get record with PromotionMaintenanceID (of main Record) , PromotionID (of main Record) , PromotionName (of main Record) and PromotionID of all the records which has PID =PromotionID of the main record

```
PromotionMaintenanceID ,PID , PromotionID ,PromotionName
1  | T1  | 12 | Promo1
2  | 12  | 22 | PromoSub
3  | 12  | 33 | PromoSub2
```

I need my result like

```
PromotionMaintenanceID | PID | PromotionID | PromotionName | Sub PromoID
1  | T1  | 12 | Promo1  |22,33
```

Any one know how the query should be?

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`. If you do a search on this site you will find many similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

This query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4840c/3)) should do what you want:

```
SELECT p1.PromotionMaintenanceID, p1.PID, p1.PromotionID, p1.PromotionName, GROUP_CONCAT(p2.PromotionID) AS `Sub PromoID`
FROM promotions p1
JOIN promotions p2
ON p2.PID = p1.PromotionID
GROUP BY p1.PromotionID
```

Output:

```
PromotionMaintenanceID  PID     PromotionID     PromotionName   Sub PromoID
1                       T1      12              Promo1          33,22
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you should be able to do a straight join (or double select depending on your favourite way)

```
SELECT
  a.PromotionID,
  a.MaintenanceId,
  a.PromotionName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.PID) as SubIds
FROM
  PromotionTable a
LEFT JOIN
  PromotionTable b
ON
  a.PromotionID = b.PID
//ADD AND's here with a.(column) = b.PID if you absolutely need all the ID's for each column to link up
GROUP BY
  a.PromotionID, a.MaintenanceID, a.PromotionName
```